# Bind keyCode == 13 to each Div.Form Submit

Tags: jquery, html, submit

Don't ask me why this is needed, but I am tasked with figuring out a way. I need to iterate through all instances of `<div class="form">` on a page and bind the enter key to the submit button within that div ONLY if that div is being used, more specifically if an input in that div is being used.

I have come up with this, which doesnt work of course, can anyone lend me a hand please?

```
    $(".form").each(function(){
    if (!$(e.target).is(this,'*')) {
        if (e.which == 13) return false;
    } else {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            $('input[type=submit]',this).submit();
        }
    }
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7X6q/1/

Comment: Is there submit associated with each <div class="form">? Can you post the html code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: And where is the form, the input and the submit button in all this ?

Comment: More precisely, are the inputs within the form that should be submitted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.form input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which===13) {
        $(this).closest('.form').find('input[type="submit"]').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Note that a submit button doesn't really do anything without a form ?

Comment: It is an asp.net site so they were looking for an alternate means if defining each forms default submit button without using ASP.net. Don't ask me...all I know is what you works works great!

Comment: No problem, I figured it was ASP from the genereted ID's etc, but it still seems a bit strange ?